# What is wrong with my simple dnsmasq setup?

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, dnsmasq

I have dnsmasq running on a server (its IP is 10.10.31.22), let's say its hostname is `mydns` here's the dnsmasq.conf:

```
domain-needed
bogus-priv
local=/argonath.mydomain.com/
interface=eth0
listen-address=127.0.0.1
no-hosts
addn-hosts=/etc/dnsmasq.hosts
expand-hosts
domain=argonath.mydomain.com
```

And here is dnsmasq.hosts:

```
10.10.31.8  mithrandir
```

Note I am only using dnsmasq for DNS, not for DHCP.

Now I have Linux and a windows box both using the dnsmasq server for their dns. On the linux box if I do `nslookup mithrandir`I get:

```
Server:     10.10.31.22
Address:    10.10.31.22#53

Name:   mithrandir
Address: 10.10.31.8
```

And on windows I get this:

```
Server: UnKnown
Address: 10.10.31.22

*** UnKnown can't find mithrandir: Non-existent domain
```

However `nslookup mithrandir.argonath.mydomain.com` on the windows box works:

```
Server: UnKnown
Address: 10.10.31.22

Name: mithrandir.argonath.jhgfs.com.au
Address: 10.10.31.8
```

My first question is, why don't I see `mydns` under "Server" for the linux box? Then of course my second question is why does the windows one fail? I assume it is to do with the server not reporting its name correctly. What have I set up wrong?

Comment: Yoyr listen-address is loopback... That doesn't sell write right...

Comment: What should it be?

Answer (score 1):

Worked it out. Windows adds a domain suffix on the end of queries, so it was actually asking for `mithrandir.companydomain.com`

(This is inside a company where all the workstations are put on the company.com domain).

After that failed, windows tried mithrandir.com which went to the wider net and came back as non existent.

Not sure how to solve the problem but at least I know it is an issue with the Windows workstation and not my dnsmasq config.